# Karma - Jasmine, Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Could not load "util"

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an error with some tests with **Karma** and **Jasmine** (*karma  4.4.1*, *jasmine-core 3.6.0* and *karma-jasmine 4.0.1*) in an **Angular 10** App. I run tests and the output is the next:

```
MyModalComponent
    ✗ Should create component
    Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Could not load "util".
    Error: Could not load "util".
        at HTMLScriptElement.__zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYerror (src/tests/mocks/gog-mock.js:70:236)
        at HTMLScriptElement.wrapFn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:763:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:406:1)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:178:1)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:487:1)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:1600:1)
        at HTMLScriptElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:1626:1)

24 04 2021 19:41:34.954:ERROR [karma-server]: UncaughtException
```

Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Please share the entire `MyModalComponent.compnent.ts`  file. without it, its impossible to debug. and hence this will soon be voted to close

Comment: but I think that's not necessary, if you check the attached log you can see that the issue is with the *karma* tool and not with the component.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing the **dist** and **coverage** folders from the project root and re-run the *tests* (i.e: `ng test`).